# Got Error when use free server in android

Tags: php, android, hosting

Got Error when use free server in android! when i try to connect php file on free server by volley using the code below it give me error ! i tryed to use local-host it work well!

the error Massage :

```html
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("0d9b98f211201b6ed929da100ab7c4ef");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://peterkameel.epizy.com/php/hello.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

enter code here

```
enter code url = "http://peterkameel.epizy.com/php/hello.php";
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest users = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            textView.setText(response);
            requestQueue.stop();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            textView.setText(error.toString());
            requestQueue.stop();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(users); here
```

Comment: what error you are getting where is your logcat?

Comment: This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's most likely a `bot` protection plugin on your server. If you have control over your server plugins, you should disable / remove it. If it's also just a free hoster you probably can't disable it. In that case this hoster is useless for you and you should search for a new hoster.

**Solution**
Changing your host could solve your problem.